# How can I install Nest.js in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: installation, nestjs

I have a problem. I can't install Nest.js in Visual Studio Code. Please help me fix this issue

npm install -g @nestjs/cli

changed 248 packages in 6s

44 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

npm fund
ttajo
├── https://github.com/sponsors/feross
│   └── safe-buffer@5.2.1, buffer@5.7.1, base64-js@1.5.1, ieee754@1.2.1
└── https://github.com/sponsors/ljharb
└── is-object@1.0.2

Comment: The message about funding is an optional message (more like an informational message) - it has nothing to do with the installation of the package... what makes you believe you did not install Nest.js?  do you get an error message?